# Inverting a function via CLP(FD) in pure Prolog

Tags: while-loop, prolog, enumerate, clpfd

Lets take this function:

```
function gcd(a, b)
   while a ≠ b
     if a > b
        a := a − b
     else
        b := b − a
   return a
```

How would we code gcd/3 in pure Prolog, so that it can be inverted. The Prolog predicate should for example compute gcd(2,3)=1. But if we would ask what are the a, b such that gcd(a,b)=1, we would also get by the same Prolog predicate:

```
/* one while iteration */
2, 1
1, 2 
/* two while iterations */
3, 1
2, 3
3, 2
1, 3 
/* Etc... */
```

Prolog seems to be especially suited since it can enumerate solutions.

Comment: @GhostCat This is normal Prolog. Even something very basic like `between(1, inf, X)` will give you infinitely many answers for X. Same goes for `length(L, N)`. The question usually is how you count the solutions (in what order you enumerate them). But the point is, as long as the infinite set is countable, it is normal to expect a Prolog predicate to enumerate it.

Comment: @TA_intern more reopen votes are thus needed. But I don't know which amount of reputation is needed.

Comment: Cannot vote to reopen. Can only "Improve this question". Sorry :-( Not reputable enough.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to literally translate the GCD function
into a Prolog code. The first clause is for when a ≠ b is false,
which means we can terminate the function. Otherwise we
recurse into the two cases:

```
euclid(A,A,A).
euclid(A,B,R) :- A #< B, C #= B-A, euclid(A,C,R).
euclid(A,B,R) :- A #> B, C #= A-B, euclid(C,B,R).
```

We can test, seems to work fine, except it has choice points.
But the choice points are kind of the price we have to pay for
using CLP(FD) and programming pure Prolog without cut:

```
?- euclid(17,13,X).
X = 1 ;
No
```

But using euclid/3 for enumeration isn't very satisfactory,
the result is only one execution branch of the GCD function:

```
?- euclid(A,B,1).
A = 1,
B = 1 ;
A = 1,
B = 2 ;
A = 1,
B = 3 ;
A = 1,
B = 4 ;
```

Now we can do the following and encode a path P through the GCD
function by a binary number. When we terminate the path will be P=1.
Otherwise we use the lower bit of P to encode which of the two remaining
clauses of the GCD were chosen:

```
euclid(A,A,1,A).
euclid(A,B,P,R) :- A #< B, C #= B-A, P #= 2*Q, Q #> 0, euclid(A,C,Q,R).
euclid(A,B,P,R) :- A #> B, C #= A-B, P #= 2*Q+1, Q #> 0, euclid(C,B,Q,R).
```

The resulting Prolog predicate is indeed bidirectional:

```
?- euclid(17,13,P,X).
P = 241,
X = 1 ;
No
?- euclid(A,B,241,1).
A = 17,
B = 13 ;
No
```

We can also use it to arbitrarily enumerate, although only with
the help of between/3 and maybe not the most efficient, but it wurks:

```
?- between(1,7,P), euclid(A,B,P,1), write(B/A), nl, fail; true.
1/1
2/1
1/2
3/1
2/3
3/2
1/3
Yes
```

**Edit 04.02.2021:**
Oh, interesting, this works also. But the result is differently ordered:

```
?- P #< 8, euclid(A,B,P,1), write(B/A), nl, fail; true.
1/1
2/1
3/1
3/2
1/2
2/3
1/3
true.
```

Comment: Fixing P before calling euclid fixes the path, so it will make many computations just to fail when it chooses a different path. I was also expecting an answer that did not need to set an upper bound.

Comment: Its not that bad, you can try ?- P=101, P #= 2*Q will fail. ?- P=101, P #= 2*Q+1 will succeed with Q=50. I tried with SWI-Prolog and Jekejeke Prolog, same result. So for a given P it will quite directly move to its target. But there is nothing in the solution that helps going from P to P+1 during enumeration, it will start all over for a new P.

Comment: but you are computing every time the whole path. I mean for enumerating, you are starting from the beginning each time building the path.

Comment: Yes, P is ground when euclid/4 is called in the last shown query. I didn't try whether P #< 8 would do something useful. Maybe?

Comment: I think the second example (the one that does not fixate P) just goes through the first branch every time, only going the the second because of your upper bound, so if you choose a large number you would first get all the solutions which go through the first branch

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses an argument to keep track of the current tier of the loop:

```
gcd(A, B, G):-
  gcd(_, A, B, G).

gcd(Tier, A, B, G):-
  Tier1 #= Tier - 1,
  Tier1 #>= 0,
  zcompare(Order, A, B),
  gcd(Order, Tier1, A, B, G).
  
gcd(=, 0, G, G, G).
gcd(>, Tier, A, B, G):-
  A1 #= A - B,
  gcd(Tier, A1, B, G).
gcd(<, Tier, A, B, G):-
  B1 #= B - A,
  gcd(Tier, A, B1, G).
```

So when you want to get a tiered enumeration you my write:

```
?- between(1,3,Tier), gcd(Tier, A,B,1), write(B/A), nl, fail; true.
1/1
1/2
2/1
1/3
2/3
3/2
3/1
true.
```

Comment: I believe that choice point is due to the second clause of gcd/4. When the first clause succeeds (i.e. found the gcd) it still has the second clause to check

Comment: Modified the code so as to fully use zcompare/3 and get rid of one of the clauses of gcd/4